# Происхождение слова Мильча

Tags: этимология

Существует достаточно много населённых пунктов, в названии которых встречается слово "Мильча".
Откуда оно происходит?

Answer (score 1):

Так как название встречается в основном в Польше, Беларуси и на западе Украины, то, вероятно, его происхождение польское. Само *Мильча* (`Milcza`) очень похоже на польское [`milczeć`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/milcze%C4%87) (*молчать*). Скорей всего, это некое женское диалектное/устаревшее прилагательное «молчая» (аналогично, например, [*Wesoła*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0_(%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0)) — *весёлая*), но я не настолько хорошо знаю польские язык и топонимику, чтобы утверждать, что это именно так.

Comment: Интересная версия, спасибо!